# How can I add mouseover support for lightview without souce declaration and make it for links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

[Lightview](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview/) is a lightbox.
If you click a link with lightview class, you can view it in a little window.
Now, I would like to add mouseover support, so I created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jj8wrbaz/3/) based on API.
Only problem with this, can't work in automatically.
I mean, must declarate the file url in the script, for example:

```
    Lightview.show('http://www.w8themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Woods-Wallpaper.jpg');
```

Why dosen't work with in normaly like this?:

```
<a href="image.png"class="lightview"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but I think this is what you are asking for. If you give the anchor an href of the image, you can target it like this:

```
Lightview.show($(this).attr("href"));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj8wrbaz/4/)

Comment: This just awsome!
You're great!

Comment: How can I close it with mouse out?

Comment: Are you sure you want to? The user might not know it does that and move the mouse.

Comment: Yeah, but I whant a tooltip and this is a easyest way get all content what I need. I mean this just a "quiq view" if the user whant thre can click for the link and there can view the content without closeing.